# Gemalto ID Bridge CT-40 with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, smartcard-reader, gemalto

I had a POS Application, and I need to access the customer identification no with the smart card reader (Gemalto ID Bridge CT-40) from my application. Is there any SDK or Dll file available on Windows to access smart card reader,
my Application is build on vb.NET.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the smart card applets installed on the card.
in general, you can send commands to the card using winscard.dll. you could find more details on https://wisnu.id/notes/developing-apdu-sender-using-winscard/

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific.

It depends on the smart card, the version of Windows etc.

These may help get you started:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-how-smart-card-sign-in-works-in-windows

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.smartcards?view=winrt-19041